# wxWidget v2.8 software. Get it works with a 3.0 lib?

Tags: c++, linux, wxwidgets

I coded a software using wxWidget 2.8 library 6 years ago.
I want it to run on a Ubuntu 16.04 which has a wxWidget 3.0 lib installed. It compiles without any errors, here is the output of my Makefile :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
wxFlasher configuration :
+ DEBUG = 0
+ UNICODE = 1
+ STATIC = 0
+ WX_VERSION = 3.0.2
+ SRC_DIR = /var/dev/wxFlasher/src
+ BUILD_DIR_BASE = /var/dev/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu
+ OUT_DIR = /var/dev/wxFlasher/out_gcc/releaseu
+ GCC_PATH = /usr/bin/gcc
+ GCC_VERSION = gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then, when I try to run the application, it says:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk2u_xrc-2.8.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to get it works?

**EDIT :**

The output of ldd  :

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffde9753000)
libwx_gtk2u_xrc-2.8.so.0 => not found
libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so.0 => not found
libwx_baseu_xml-2.8.so.0 => not found
libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbf56ffd000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbf56de0000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbf56a17000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbf5670e000)/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbf5737f000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbf564f8000)
```

in wxconfig.mak :

```
WX_CONFIG := wx-config

# argument for debug
ifeq ("$(DEBUG)", "0")
  WX_CONFIG_ARGS += --debug=no
else
  WX_CONFIG_ARGS += --debug=yes
endif

# argument for unicode
ifeq ("$(UNICODE)", "0")
  WX_CONFIG_ARGS += --unicode=no
else
  WX_CONFIG_ARGS += --unicode=yes
endif

# argument for static
ifeq ("$(STATIC)", "0")
  WX_CONFIG_ARGS += --static=no
else
  WX_CONFIG_ARGS += --static=yes
endif

# get wxWidgets configuration
WX_LIBS := $(shell $(WX_CONFIG) --libs $(WX_CONFIG_ARGS))
WX_FLAGS := $(shell $(WX_CONFIG) --cppflags $(WX_CONFIG_ARGS))
WX_VERSION := $(shell $(WX_CONFIG) --version $(WX_CONFIG_ARGS))
```

wx-config --libs returns me this :

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread   -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to re-compile it with the new library version. Judging from the error message you received you didn't do it or the compilation was unsuccessful.

Also, make sure you read the documentation about upgrading to 3.0, as it is almost a guarantee you will have errors.

Comment: I edited my question, no error during compilation and I well compiled with 3.0 version... I don't understand what's going on

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud, so if you run "ldd <program_name>" what is the output? Also did you compiled the library yourself or install it from the repo?

Comment: question edited. I think I installed it from the repo !

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud, I think you OS has version 2.8 and 3.0 mixed. I would suggest to remove any wx references in /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib and (possibly) in your directory. Then install wxGTK-3.0 and wxGTK-3.0 dev packages and recompile you program. Or better yet - download the sources from the official download page, compile them yourself and recompile the application after that.